# Touchpad pointer stuck after suspend/awake

Tags: suspend, touchpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 18 on a laptop (recently purchased) with an Nvidia GPU Geforce 1070, and I've configured it to use the Synaptics driver based on [this blog post](https://williambharding.com/blog/linux-to-macbook/linux-with-a-macbook-touchpad-feel-pt-2/).

When I close the lid (suspend) and later re-open the lid (resume), it often ends up where the pointer is stuck and unresponsive to using the touchpad.

How can I go about debugging this?  I seem to have lost the error logs, but the last time it happened I saw errors in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` followed by a line that said `UnloadModule: "synaptics"`, but I wasn't clear on how to further diagnose it.

The next time it happens I'll post a follow-up with more detailed logs.

Comment: Here is a snapshot of the /var/log/Xorg* logs taken after a resume where the touchpad pointer got completely stuck: https://ptpb.pw/poO_  What could be causing the `[   336.628] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"`